# Cannot login/Unable to login django tenant

Tags: django, multi-tenant

**Background:** I am developing my first multi tenant application with django. I have successfully followed the tutorial given by https://github.com/tomturner/django-tenants

It was easy to create tenants, I could create user/superuser in public and tenant schemas and could login with those users in corresponding tenants at locahost:8000/admin/ and mytenant.localhost:8000/admin/

But needed a global auth for users related to multiple tenants(per domain rather than separate login for each subdomain) so I used https://github.com/Corvia/django-tenant-users

I am still successful to create tenants and users (physical schemas in database as well) using following code. but issue is

**I am unable to access (even after success in login) admin page both at http://localhost:8000/admin and http://mytenant.localhost:8000/admin with any of created users and sadly I get no message at all**

```
    public_owner = "owner@local"
    create_public_tenant("localhost", public_owner)
    public_admin = "admin@local"
    TenantUser.objects.create_superuser('xxx', public_admin)

    tenant_super_user = "admin@" + tenant_name
    TenantUser.objects.create_superuser('xxx', tenant_super_user)
    provision_tenant(tenant_name, tenant_name, tenant_super_user)
```

**More details:**
I tried debugging my login function of django, It successfully logins in and its 302 status code promises to redirect to `/admin` and it also shows that authenticated user (request.user) is superuser, but does not go to admin page

My Installed apps is settings.py are

```
    SHARED_APPS = (
        'django_tenants',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'tenant_users.permissions',
        'tenant_users.tenants',
        'customers',  # you must list the app where your tenant model resides in
        'users',
    )

    TENANT_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'tenant_users.permissions',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'tenant_only',
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

**You said two things in your question**

1. There is no message shown when you login to admin this is because your Session Cookie Domain is improperly configured see below code.
2. You want a single login for all your tenants and they must have the ability to jump between sub-domains that they have access to.

**SOLUTION**

**A.** Remove the django.contrib.sessions from Tenant App tuple.
*Your application definition should look something like this in settings.py*

```
# Application definition
SHARED_APPS = (
    'django_tenants',  # mandatory
 # ...
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth', # Defined in both shared apps and tenant apps
    'django.contrib.contenttypes', # Defined in both shared apps and tenant apps
    'tenant_users.permissions', # Defined in both shared apps and tenant apps
    'tenant_users.tenants', # Defined only in shared apps
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'public', # Custom defined app that contains the TenantModel. Must NOT exist in TENANT_APPS
    'users', # Custom app that contains the new User Model (see below). Must NOT exist in TENANT_APPS
# ...
)

TENANT_APPS=[
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth', # Defined in both shared apps and tenant apps
    'django.contrib.contenttypes', # Defined in both shared apps and tenant apps
    'tenant_users.permissions', # Defined in both shared apps and tenant apps
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'tenant',
]
```

You have to do this so that public schema handle all the sessions rather than tenant schemas.

**B.** Set the SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None (if you are testing on localhost) else
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.yourweb.com'. You cannot have that cross domain single login on localhost but once your app gets deployed with your domain name it will support one login and multiple tenant access.

```
    if DEBUG:
        SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
    else:
        SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.yourdomain.com'
```

PS: On localhost you have to login everytime when you jump from one sub-domain to another sub-domain this is because the session cookie domain require two "." to identify a domain which is not in ".localhost" (there is more technical answer for this question that I had found previously here which I will link later)